# JQuery: IE11 AJAX error handler not giving error information

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, error-handling

There is quite a discrepancy between what error information JQuery gets from an AJAX call in Firefox and IE11:

```
ajaxData = {id: 1234, quantity: 3};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: BASE_URL + 'ajax/this-page-does-not-exist.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: ajaxData,
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // in Firefox:
        //  - xhr.responseText has the "Not found" HTML message returned by the server
        //  - xhr.status is 404
        //  - textStatus is 'error'
        //  - errorThrown is 'Not Found'
        // in IE11:
        //  - xhr.responseText is empty
        //  - xhr.status is 0
        //  - textStatus is 'error'
        //  - errorThrown is empty

    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
        // ...
    }
});
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: What happens if you use fail instead of error? Error, success and complete were deprecated in jQuery 1.8.

Comment: Can you give an example of how the url is formatted?

Comment: @JayBlanchard no, `error: fn` is not depreciated, `.error(fn)` is.

Comment: Example POST data now added to code snippet

Answer (score 1):

this may be the same as the one I asked here:

[IE11 returns status 0 during Ajax POST operation from an iFrame (XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820444/ie11-returns-status-0-during-ajax-post-operation-from-an-iframe-xmlhttprequest)

Microsoft said that they will investigate the problem.